# SQL Server too happy about adding the day and month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm starting with this query.

```
select 
  count(datepart(day, SomeTime)) as NumberOf, 
  datepart(day, SomeTime) as DaySansMonth
    from PMStationTightenings
    group by datepart(day, SomeTime)
```

It does what's supposed but not conveniently presented. So I remodel it to include the month as well.

```
select 
  count(datepart(day, SomeTime)) as NumberOf, 
  datepart(month, SomeTime) + ' ' + datepart(day, SomeTime) as DayAndMonth
    from PMStationTightenings
    group by datepart(month, SomeTime) + ' ' + datepart(day, SomeTime)
```

The computer tries to be smart and adds the numbers anyway, so instead of e.g. *8 5* I get *13*. Less than perfect. Why? (I understand it interprets the two numbers as integers, of course, but why? There's clearly a space between...)

Anyhow, I go ahead and make it trip but putting in stuff it can't add. Now I think to myself "HA! got ya!". Would you believe - the stupid computer barks at me throwing these nasty red stuff like if *I* was to have made a mistake. Unbelievable! What a nerve!   :)

```
select 
  count(datepart(day, SomeTime)) as NumberOf, 
  datepart(month, SomeTime) + '|' + datepart(day, SomeTime) as DayAndMonth
    from PMStationTightenings
    group by datepart(month, SomeTime) + '|' + datepart(day, SomeTime)
```

How can I made the computer by b!"#¤ and force it to give me a month/day combo from the DB?

Comment: Why? Because, rather annoyingly, when you do int + string in SQL Server, it tries to convert the string to an int before doing addition, rather than the sensible option of casting the int to a string and concatenating. The string `' '` gets converted to 0, so you end up with 5 + 0 + 8, which is 13.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Aha - ' ' is converted to 0. That's unexpected (at least given my level of ignorance regarding SQL).Intuitively, I'd prefer automatic conversion *to a string* (no casting issues), than *to an integer* (possible poofage to be expected).

Comment: Just as a footnote: if Microsoft implemented the ANSI SQL standard for concatenation (`||`), rather than overloading `+`, this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Allan As a footnote, - and I stress that I'm a huge fan of Billy's company overall and a devoted MS-monkey - if Microsoft implemented standards hell would freeze over, we'd see Thursday twice a week, pigs would fly (like they do in Hay Day, hihi) and a bunch of other stuff according to folkloristic beliefs in a culture of anyone's choice.   :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Jim already explained how you can fix this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25380013/2186023), here is the `WHY`.

Quoting from [SQL Server's Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx):

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the
>   rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
>   precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion,
>   an error is returned.

You are combining `INT` (return value from `DATEPART`) AND (N)`VARCHAR`, but `INT` has higher precedence than (N)`VARCHAR`), so SQL Server tries to treat the whole thing as `INT`.

In general you should try to avoid implicit conversions and be as explicit as you can if you are dealing with different data types in one expression.
So just cast/convert your values into the type that is appropriate.

EDIT: corrected part about the data types involved, due to Anthony Grist

Comment: They're combining INT and (N)VARCHAR, not DATETIME(2). The DATEPART function returns an INT. Though in general everything you've said is correct.

Comment: +1 Nice! Now I'm torn - whose reply do I check as an answer?! Both are good, both combined are a perfect answer. Both came at the same time according to the ticker...

Comment: Well as I linked Jim's answer in my post... his was first if that's what you're after ;)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I'd be tempted to go with this answer since it explains the *why*.

Answer (score 7):

Try casting the value to a varchar:

```
CAST(datepart(month, SomeTime) AS VARCHAR(2)) 
+ ' ' 
+ CAST(datepart(day, SomeTime) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

Comment: +1 for briefness and clarity. Who's getting the green check and cool 10 experience points now?!